# Why does, boundary of $D$ equal $\left\{ {{P_\Delta }(\lambda ):\left\| {{\Delta _j}} \right\| = \varepsilon {w_j}} \right\}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let

- ${A_j},{\Delta _j} \in {\mathbb{C}^{n \times n}},(j = 0,1,2....m)$
- ${\rm{P(}}\lambda {\rm{) = }}{{\rm{A}}_m}{\lambda ^m} + .....{A_1}\lambda  + {A_0}$ is a matrix polynomial,  and $\lambda $ is a complex variable.$\lambda$ is eigenvalue of $P(\lambda )$ if $\det P(\lambda ) = 0$
- ${P_\Delta }(\lambda ) = ({A_m} + {\Delta _m}){\lambda ^m} + ....... + ({A_1} + {\Delta _1}){\lambda ^1} + ({A_0} + {\Delta _0})$
- $\left\| {{.}} \right\| $ is any subordinate matrix norm.
- ${w_j} \ge 0,(j = 0,1....,m)$
- $D = \left\{ {{P_\Delta }(\lambda ):\left\| {{\Delta _j}} \right\| \le \varepsilon {w_j}} ,j=0,1,2,...,m\right\}$

Why does, boundary of $D$ equal $\left\{ {{P_\Delta }(\lambda ):\left\| {{\Delta _j}} \right\| = \varepsilon {w_j}},j=0,1,2,...,m \right\}$?

Comment: Let $\partial S$ denote the boundary of $S$. For any invertible linear map $T:V\to W$ and any set $S\subset V$, $\partial(T(S))=T(\partial(S))$.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom - Thank you, why this formula is true ? And is it true that we define $T:\left\{ {({\Delta _1},...,{\Delta _m}):\left\| {{\Delta _j}} \right\| \le \varepsilon {w_j}} \right\} \to {M_n}$ such that $T({\Delta _1},...,{\Delta _m}) = {P_\Delta }(\lambda )$?

Comment: technically that would be an *affine* map as opposed to a linear map, but that could work and the same idea applies. As to why the formula is true: it's because any invertible linear (or affine) map between finite dimensional spaces is a homeomorphism. In particular, if you wanted to "prove" that this works, you'd want to show that $T$ maps open sets to open sets, in addition to being a continuous bijection.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom - Therefore, can we say, this formula is true for interior?

Comment: Yes! ${}{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: @Omnomnomnom - Is there  a reference to prove this formula?

Comment: one result which works here (and is more powerful than what you need) is the [open mapping theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_mapping_theorem_(functional_analysis))

Comment: @Omnomnomnom - Please see this paper in page 10 and 11 (...for each $j$ and equality holds for at least one $j$.)http://www.math.ntua.gr/~ppsarr/mcblp.pdf